# Most optimized way or data structure for this set?

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a hierarchical data set that is returned by a web service.  I do not have control over this service or structure and have to make best of it...

```
{
  "Parent": [
       {
          "ParentId":"yyyyyy",
          "Children": [
               {
                  "ChildId":"xxxxxx",
                  "Grandchildren": [
                         {
                             "GrandchildId":"nnnnnnn"
                         },
                   ]
               }
          ]
       },
   ]
```

So a Parent has an array of children.  Each child element has an array of "grandchildren".  It's literally JSON that's being returned by the web service.

What I have done is that I created a dictionary type where the key is the Parent Id and the value is the Children array.  That way, I can easily look up the children of a parent.  Similarly, I have another dictionary/hash where the key is the Child Id and I can use that to look up the array of Grandchildren.

Here's where it gets interesting.

I am looking for a way to be able to quickly determine the Child and/or Parent from the Grandchild.

What would be the best way to do that?

The brute force way I can think of and am tempted to use is to create an array or list of all the grandchild elements, and for each element, give it a parent and grandparent property that points to those objects.

I am doing this in JavaScript.  However, I am more interested from a CS perspective what's the optimal solution for this?  What data structure should be used?

Comment: Define "optimal". Lookup speed? Re–indexing speed (assuming one is used to speed lookups)? Those may depend on how big the data set is and how often it's changed, replaced or otherwise modified.

Comment: Yes, optimized for look up speed.  The structure will be periodically replaced (entirely).

Comment: Do the id's have any logical order to them? Numbering system that makes sense as to when they were created?

Comment: @Beebunny—then if the structure isn't too big (say 1,000 parents or less) and is as shallow as you've indicated, I'd just do your reverse index (child to parent and grandparent) because it's very simple and can be built when the object is replaced. It should be easy to build while the forward indexes are built.